# Custom Protocol Message hash

Tags: hash, cryptography, protocols

I'm developing a custom internet/wire application level based protocol and am currently using SHA1 however it's inefficiently increasing the amount of bytes required for transfer.

The algorithm should create a small and efficient hash of [Message] (which can be any binary data)

I've searched google and parts of wikipedia and cannot find a suitable hash algorithm.

So you know, the protocol is like:

```
[Length] [LengthOfHash][LengthOfMessage][Hash][ Message.... ]
```

Can anyone suggest or provide information on a suitable hash algorithm and if possible an example implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with the hash?

You can truncate an SHA-1 hash to any length you want, but if you truncate it too far, it may be possible for an attacker to defeat the protection the hash is supposed to offer just by brute force.

In particular, based on [these benchmarks](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html), even a somewhat aging 1.83 GHz desktop CPU can evaluate about 2<sup>23</sup> SHA-1 hashes per second per core.  This means that, if you truncate your hash to, say, 32 bits, an attacker can easily find a string hashing to any value they want in less than 10 minutes — or even faster, if they have a fast modern multicore CPU.

(Of course, there are even faster ways to brute force hashes. [Bitcoin miners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#Bitcoin_mining) like to use graphics cards, which can [apparently](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) reach up to 2<sup>31</sup> hashes per second — and that's for SHA-256, which is typically about 50% slower than SHA-1.  And, of course, the work parallelizes really easily, so you can just pay a few bucks to rent a few hundred extra CPUs from Amazon EC2, or even buy/build some custom hash-cracking hardware.  Or, if you're a *real* black hat hacker, just use your botnet of zombie computers and pay nothing.)

To be reasonably safe against brute force [preimage attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), I'd recommend a hash length of *at least* 64 bits: even with 1000 computers each trying 2<sup>32</sup> hashes per second, that would still take several months to crack by brute force.

Also, if you also need [collision resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) (i.e. the inability of an attacker to feed you two different strings that hash to the same value), then you need to double that to 128 bits due to the [birthday effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).
You also shouldn't use SHA-1, anyway, since there are [known better-than-brute-force collision finding attacks on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Attacks).  Use one of the [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) functions instead.

Comment: @llmari karonen Basically i just want to ensure that the payload sent/received from server/client is in-tact and hasn't been modified mistakenly in transmission. Of course it'll also stop some script kiddies from trying to get free coins etc etc. It doesn't need to be bullet proof (if that's even possible) but it shouldn't be weak.

Comment: Then you probably want a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code), not a hash. The same issues about truncation apply, except that collision attacks are generally not a concern with MACs, and that the only way to carry out a brute force attack on a MAC is to feed guessed MACs to your server until it accepts one. With proper rate limiting, this may let you get away with a shorter MAC, though I'd still generally recommend at least 64 bits just to be safe. Also, don't forget to include a message number and/or a timestamp in your messages to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: "Also, don't forget to include a message number and/or a timestamp in your messages to prevent replay attacks."

What do you mean?

Comment: Somebody could capture an entire valid message, MAC and all, that says e.g. something like "I just killed a monster, give me some coins.", and resend it repeatedly. If there's nothing in the message that would let you recognize that you've seen it before, that could give them as many free coins as they want. Other variations are possible too, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) for details.